# Elm 2 player same keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, elm

How can I take two inputs from the keyboard form two different players (<kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>) and (<kbd>W</kbd> ,<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>) and not interrupt the movement of the other player?

Here's my code:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd.Cmd Msg )
update (KeyMsg keyCode) model =
case keyCode of
    39 ->
        ( { model | counterH = model.counterH + 10 }, Cmd.none )

    40 ->
        ( { model | counterV = model.counterV + 10 }, Cmd.none )

    37 ->
        ( { model | counterH = checkerfunc model.counterH }, Cmd.none )

    38 ->
        ( { model | counterV = checkerfunc model.counterV }, Cmd.none )

    83 ->
        ( { model | counterV2 = model.counterV2 + 10 }, Cmd.none )

    65 ->
        ( { model | counterH2 = checkerfunc model.counterH2 }, Cmd.none )

    68 ->
        ( { model | counterH2 = model.counterH2 + 10 }, Cmd.none )

    87 ->
        ( { model | counterV2 = checkerfunc model.counterV2 }, Cmd.none )

    _ ->
        ( model, Cmd.none )
```

I want the code to be structured similarly.

Comment: The code looks correct to me. You're changing different fields for arrow keys and wasd. Changing one should not alter the state of the other user. What doesn't work?

Comment: So, since its a two player game I'm facing a problem where movement of one player stops the other player. I can press and hold and get increments based on that but that is solely for one player. Only if player 1 and player 2 presses at the exact same time, they move together.